# Mismatching contact id's while trying to blacklist phonenumbers

Tags: android, android-contacts

I'm using the contact picker like below to get the id of a contact.

```
public void pickContact() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    intent.setType(Phone.CONTENT_TYPE); // Show user only contacts w/ phone numbers
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
}
```

Then I retrieve the contact id from the uri returned by the above using this. And store that as a reference.

```
public static long getContactIdByUri(Context context, Uri uri)
{
    Log.d(TAG, uri.toString());
    String[] projection = { Contacts._ID };
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    try
    {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Contacts._ID);
        long id = -1;

        if(idx != -1)
        {
            id = cursor.getLong(idx);
        }
        return id;
    }
    finally
    {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Later on when a text message arrives I fetch the phone number and based on that I try to look up the contact id using the following.

```
public static long getContactIdByPhoneNumber(Context context, String phoneNumber) {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
    String[] projection = new String[] { PhoneLookup._ID };
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return -1;
    }
    int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup._ID);
    long id = -1;
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        id = cursor.getLong(idx);
    }
    if(cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }
    return id;
}
```

The problem is that those two id's doesn't match!

So basically the question goes how can I get an id from the contact picker which I can match when looking up a phone number with PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI. Which I can also use to get additional information about the contact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url returned from the contact picker refers to the ContactsContract.Data provider which is joined with ContactsContract.RawContacts which again contains CONTACT_ID.

So extracting the actual contact id is trivial using the method below.

```
   public static long getContactIdByDataUri(Context context, Uri uri)
   {
          String[] projection = new String[] { Data.CONTACT_ID };
          Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
          long id = -1;
          if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                 id = cursor.getLong(0);
          }
          return id;
   }
```